# how to change background of the augmented_faces_java sample in ARCore?

Tags: android, android-studio, graphics, arcore, android-augmented-reality

as you know this is the sample of fox filter appears in front the face but I want to change that the fox filter should appear in front of an image. I mean the only difference is: the display will show an image at background not a person. Do you have any ideas? by the way I am working on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is by adding it with:

1. image -> so the others can see what you mean by "this is the sample of fox filter ..."
2. what code you have written to tackle this problem?